# Jquery, add & remove element on hover

Tags: jquery, effects, addition, element

I came a cross a problem which I tried pretty much everything without a solution.

```
$('a.hovered').hover(function () {
    $(this).after(' <img src="images/icons/famfamfam/silk/user_go.png" />');
},function () {
    $(this).remove(' <img src="images/icons/famfamfam/silk/user_go.png" />');
});
```

Of course I tried many versions of this remove() without any success. I will be glad if anyone could help me out with this problem.

Additionally I would like to add effect of fadeIn() and fadeOut() but of course this wasn't successful also.

I can add the image but I can't remove it (even fadeIn didn't work while I can successfully add images).

Thank you for your help and time in advance.

Comment: You didn't explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Tomalak Quote:"I can add the image but I can't remove it. "

Comment: @das_weezul: "I can't remove it" is _not_ an error description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really don't want to do that. Your code will be quicker, clearer and easier to maintain if you just show and hide an image that always exist.

Just put the `img` into your html with and id set and `style="display: none;"` to hide it.

Your javascript code then becomes:

```
$('a.hovered').hover(function () {
    $("#user_go").show();
},function () {
    $("#user_go").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Name you elements, it'll make life easier for you, i.e.:

```
$('a.hovered').hover(function () {
    $(this).after(' <img id="user_go" src="images/icons/famfamfam/silk/user_go.png" />');
},function () {
    $("#user_go").remove();
});
```

Comment: You have some unnecessary DOM traversal there!

Comment: The element is inserted *after* `$(this)`, not within it. So `$(this).remove('#user_go');` should fail as it's not contained within the element set being offered.

Answer (score 0):

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) doesn't take a piece of HTML:

```
$('a.hovered').hover(function () {
    $(this).after(' <img src="images/icons/famfamfam/silk/user_go.png" id="go_image" />');
},function () {
    $('#go_image').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant reference to created object in such manner, try

```
$('a.hovered').hover(function () {
    $(this).after(' <img src="images/icons/famfamfam/silk/user_go.png" id="addedImage"/>');},
    $('#addedImage').remove();
});
```

Yep, and while I write, two other post the same stuff :)

Answer (score -2):

why not just do this?

```
$('a.hovered').hover(function () {      
$(this).after(' <img src="images/icons/famfamfam/silk/user_go.png" />');  },
function () {
$(this).find('img').remove();
 });
```

Comment: You are forgetting, that selector is referencing to anchor element, as IMG is put outside, it cant be found, within anchor element.