# add image on leaflet map on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, leaflet

Hi I'm creating a webpage in which I eventually want my leaflet map clickable. But I want to show a 'click here' image on the map that appears on hover. I looked up the following questions for solutions via both css and jquery but could get close to what I wanted.

[How to display image over image on hover with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361924/how-to-display-image-over-image-on-hover-with-css)

[Jquery, add & remove element on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497866/jquery-add-remove-element-on-hover)

Here is my simplified code

```
css
body {
padding: 0px;
background-color: white;
}

div#map {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
position: center;
border-color: #000000;
/* -moz-border-radius: 5px; */
/* -webkit-border-radius: 10px; */
border-radius: 30px;
/*box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;*/
z-index: 0;
}

#pattern {
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
}

html
<div id="map">

</div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

js
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.7241745, -73.9841674], 11);

L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/    tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ',
maxZoom: 16
}).addTo(map);

var mylayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
```

Sample Image: http://nbchardballtalk.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/click-here-large2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the image as a child to the #map element, and add :hover css to #map, like if the image is #hand:

```
#map #hand{display:none;} 
#map:hover #hand{display:block;}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/azp74rgj/)

HTH,
-Ted